# Como matar um processo de um usuário especifico no Windows Server?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, processo

Tenho uma aplicação em C# que ao final precisa matar um processo do usuário que executou, mas como estou em um Terminal Server (Windows Server) e existem vários usuários *logados*, quando coloco o comando para matar o processo

```
Process[] processo = Process.GetProcessesByName("IEDriverServer");

    foreach (Process process in processo)
    {
        process.Kill();// finaliza processo
    }
```

Ele mata de todos os usuários logados no Terminal Server (Windows Server), existe alguma forma de matar somente o processo do usuário que executou minha aplicação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo essa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/429248/221800) dá para fazer isto:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
bool rdpclipFound = false;
foreach (Process theprocess in processlist) {
    String ProcessUserSID = GetProcessInfoByPID(theprocess.Id);
    String CurrentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Replace("SERVERNAME\\",""); 
    if (theprocess.ProcessName == "rdpclip" && ProcessUserSID == CurrentUser) {
        theprocess.Kill();
        rdpclipFound = true;
    }
}
Process.Start("rdpclip");
if (rdpclipFound) {
   MessageBox.Show("rdpclip.exe successfully restarted");
} else {
   MessageBox.Show(@"rdpclip was not running under your username.
       It has been started, please try copying and pasting again.");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/Process.cs).

Obviamente precisa de algumas adaptações. Aí está fixo qual é o processo. Mas acho que deu para ver onde ele pega a informação do usuário e compara para saber se é do usuário ou não e se deve matá-lo. Lá tem outra resposta que não usa o usuário atual. E tem *link* para outras soluções.

Outra solução mais próximo do que precisa com outra abordagem em outra [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1011386/221800).

```
static void KillProcessByNameAndUserName(string processName, string userName) {
    var processes = from p in Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)
                    where GetProcessOwner(p.Id) == userName
                    select p;
    foreach(Process p in processes) p.Kill();
}

static string GetProcessOwner(int processId) {
    string query = “Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessID = “ + processId;
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    ManagementObjectCollection processList = searcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList) {
        string[] argList = new string[] { string.Empty };
        int returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(obj.InvokeMethod(“GetOwner”, argList));
        if (returnVal == 0)
            return argList[0];
    }
    return “NO OWNER”;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/Process2.cs).